# What could cause an internal 500 server error where a website image alternately shows up fine but when refresh is pressed gets a 500 error?

Tags: server, internals

We have a website where pages will load OK and then get an internal 500 server error on images, js libraries, and css libraries. Try the following link and refresh the link 6 or more times:

https://www.skywalker.com/Images/products/small/QFX1031.jpg

Alternately, the image will show and then get the following:

[image: 500 Internal server error.]

We had made no changes to our website prior to this error showing up.

Does anyone have an idea as to what could be causing this?

Thank you.

We have hired an outside consultant who could find nothing wrong. It should not be a website coding error, since this is a direct link to the image. We have inspected the page which just says "failed to load resource".

It seems that this might be an error with the server setup which is beyond our expertise. The setup is we have a host server and two virtual servers running on this host server. Our website is one of the virtual servers.